# Implement bokeh blur with C++

Tags: c++, blur

We would like to perform bokeh blur on a image. I have tried to test some code below but could not get Circle of Confusion on bright point.

```
 void bokeh(unsigned char *Input, unsigned char *Output, int Width, int Height, int Stride, int Radius)
{
    int Channels = Stride / Width;
    int rsq = fmax(1, sqrtf(Radius));
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    { 
        unsigned char * LinePD = Output + y*Stride;
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            unsigned int sum[3] = { 0 };
            unsigned int weightsum = 0;
            for (int ny = std::max(0, y - Radius); ny < std::min(y + Radius, Height); ny++)
            {
                const    unsigned char * sampleLine = Input + ny*Stride;

                for (int nx = std::max(0, x - Radius); nx < std::min(x + Radius, Width); nx++)
                { 
                    if (sqrtf(nx - x) + sqrtf(ny - y) < rsq)
                    {
                        const    unsigned char * sample = sampleLine + nx*Channels;
                        const    unsigned char&R = sample[0];
                        const    unsigned char&G = sample[1];
                        const    unsigned char&B = sample[2];
                        float weight = sqrtf((unsigned char)((21627 * R + 21627 * G + 21627 * B) >> 16));
                        
                        for (int c = 0; c < Channels; c++)
                        {
                            sum[c] += weight*sample[c];
                        }
                        weightsum += weight;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < Channels; c++)
            {
                LinePD[c] = ClampToByte(sum[c] / weightsum);
            } 
            LinePD += Channels;
        }
    }
}
```

The source image is:

[image: source image]

The result is:

[image: result]

while I expect effect is which like circular in pictures below
[image: expect effect]

seems that I replace `sqrtf(nx - x) + sqrtf(ny - y) < rsq`
with
`powf(nx - x, 2.0) + powf(ny - y, 2.0) < powf(Radius, 2)`
and replace `float weight = sqrtf((unsigned char)((21627 * R + 21627 * G + 21627 * B) >> 16));`
with
`float weight = (R + G + B)*1.0f/3.0f;`
I could get [image] bokeh blur effect, so how to set the weight to by brightness?

Comment: `sqrtf(nx - x) + sqrtf(ny - y) < rsq` -- I don't think that's the right formula for the interior of a circle.

Comment: Is `brokeh` the mis-spelled `bokeh` ?

Comment: yes, bokeh blur

Comment: I am not aware of bokeh blur and hence do not understand what the expected result is and how it differs from the shown result. Please describe both.

Comment: @Chifred Could you paste the expected result image, or something like it? I also don't visually know what the expected result is.

Comment: instead of `sqrtf(nx - x) + sqrtf(ny - y) < rsq` use `(nx - x)*(nx - x) + (ny - y)*(ny - y) < rsq*rsq`

Comment: I do know nothing about the problem, but one piece of advice i can give to improve code quality here is to pickup a naming convention and sticking to it, in your code most variables are `Pascal Case` so why we have `sum`, `rsq`, `weightsum`, also avoid `magic number` and `duplication` in `21627 * R + 21627 * G + 21627 * B`. plus I feel like the same naming conventin is wrong with methods also, as in `bokeh` and `ClampToByte`. Better code will result in more reability which among other things will let you point the errors easier.